# SMS applied to a local system

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I am doing a local billing system that needs sms as its feature. I tried using *twilio.com* for the SMS but I can't understand the PHP code that is given by twilio. Does anyone knows another way of applying SMS to a local system?

Comment: Could you post the code and show us what you've tried allready?

Comment: check this - https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto

Comment: Have you tried running through the quickstart guide (https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest), that should get you up and sending messages fairly quickly. Then you can apply it to your system.

Comment: Thank you for the links.